# Array filtering using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to find the difference between arrays.

I have 2 arrays:

arrayA:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "4"
    },
    {
        "id": "7"
    },
    {
        "id": "5"
    }
]
```

arrayB:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "5"
    }
]
```

I want to get those ids which are not present in `arrayB` using Typescript

Expected response:

```
[
    {
        "id": "4"
    },
    {
        "id": "7"
    }
]
```

Comment: There are several ways of doing this in JavaScript. The linked post about the general algorithm(s) even has a few TypeScript solutions. Please make an attempt first, then asking about _specific_ code is a better idea, e.g. if you have trouble converting the existing JS code to TS.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Neither of the linked posts offer solution for array of objects

Comment: Objects either need to be compared properly (in the quadratic complexity approaches that compare every element with every element) or serialized properly (in the linear approaches that create a hash map). Comparison is explained in the second linked post, serialization can be done with `JSON.stringify`. And a quick `Ctrl`+`F` for “objects” reveals another candidate (using Underscore.js): [How to use underscore's "intersection" on objects?](/q/8672383/4642212). Also [this answer](/a/52430020/4642212) directly addresses arrays of objects, so yes, they do.